# React-Native: Access to key prop in TextInput

Tags: react-native, key, textinput

I try to access the key prop in TextInput to save it in the state (and then in Redux). I create in an array so many TextInput fields as I got from my first screen:

```
render() {
    const { playerAmount } = this.props;
    var textBoxes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < playerAmount; i++) {
      var placeholderText = 'Player ' + (i + 1);
      textBoxes.push(
        <TextInput
          key = {i+1}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            const Player = Object.assign({}, this.state.Player, { playerName: text, playerNumber: this.props.key});
            this.setState({ Player });
          }}
          placeholder={placeholderText}
          placeholderTextColor="grey"
        >
        </TextInput>

      );
```

Now I try to set the state of the playerNumber with the key prop. I tried it with `key / {key} / this.props.key`

Constructor:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = 
    {
      Player: 
      {
        playerName: "",
        playerNumber: 0
      }
    }

  }
```

As you can see I am pretty new to React-Native. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do this?

```
render() {
  const { playerAmount } = this.props;
  var textBoxes = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < playerAmount; i++) {
    var placeholderText = 'Player ' + (i + 1);
    const key = i+1;
    textBoxes.push(
          <TextInput
              key = {key}
              onChangeText={(text) => {
                const Player = Object.assign({}, this.state.Player, { playerName: text, playerNumber: key});
                this.setState({ Player });
              }}
              placeholder={placeholderText}
              placeholderTextColor="grey"
          >
          </TextInput>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
Why is it working like that and not if I put the `key = {i+1}`into the JSX element? 
Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Firebase extends React.Component{
  state={
    name:'',
    number:'',

  }
  onChangeTextInput = key => val => {
    this.setState({[key]:val})
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <TextInput
        value={this.state.name}
        onChangeText={this.onChangeTextInput('name')}
        />
         <TextInput
        value={this.state.number}
        onChangeText={this.onChangeTextInput('number')}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```